# how to update single column in one table when two column are match in another table?

Tags: sql, oracle, select, sql-update

Everyone I am beginner in SQL.

I have two tables like first, second.

`pid` column of first table and `pid` column of second table are same. I have to get `price` from the first table and `quantity` from second table, multiply those values (final) and update that final values in second table at the `price` column.

I tried but it doesn't work. Can anyone help me? Thanks in advance.

**FIRST TABLE**

```
Name   Null?    Type         
------ -------- ------------ 
PID    NOT NULL NUMBER(38)   
PNAME  NOT NULL VARCHAR2(20) 
PPRICE NOT NULL FLOAT(126)   
PAVAIL NOT NULL NUMBER(38)
```

**SECOND TABLE**

```
Name         Null?    Type         
------------ -------- ------------ 
ORDERID      NOT NULL NUMBER(38)   
PID                   NUMBER(38)   
CUSTOMERNAME NOT NULL VARCHAR2(20) 
PHNO         NOT NULL NUMBER(38)   
QTY          NOT NULL NUMBER(38)   
PRICE        NOT NULL FLOAT(126)
```

I used this query, but it doesn't work:

```
update first f, second s
SET s.price = f.pprice * s.qty
where  s.pid  EXISTS (select second.pid from first, second
                      where (first.pid=second.pid);
```

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (That update version is product specific.)

Comment: I am using oracle sql developer

Answer (score 1):

Oracle does not support update join syntax.  One workaround is to use an update with a correlated subquery.

```
UPDATE second s
SET s.price = s.qty * (SELECT f.pprice FROM first f WHERE f.pid = s.pid)
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM first f WHERE f.pid = s.pid)
```

The exists clause is necessary to make sure that a record in `second` which does not match to anything in `first` does not have its price update to `NULL`.  If this can't happen, or you don't care if it does, then you may also remove the `WHERE` clause.

Comment: what does it mean (SELECT 1 FROM first f WHERE f.pid = s.pid)

Comment: I explained that in my answer.  Reload your page perhaps.

Comment: Oracle does support update/insert using joins. The MERGE statement does this and its pretty powerful as well.

Answer (score 0):

Update using a join is done with the [MERGE](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/statements_9016.htm#SQLRF01606) statement in Oracle and that's what you need. In your case:

```
MERGE INTO second a
     USING FIRST b
        ON (a.pid = b.pid)
WHEN MATCHED
THEN
   UPDATE SET a.price = b.price * a.qty;
```

Comment: Please don't denigrate other people's answers by telling them that yours is much better.

Comment: When I said much better I meant the MERGE syntax and not my answer. I think my language could be misconstrued. I'll update my comment. Apologies if it offended you.

Answer (score 0):

Check this statement:

```
update second s
set s.price = s.qty * (select f.pprice from first f where f.pid = s.pid )
where exists (select f.pprice from first f where f.pid = s.pid );
```

Answer (score -1):

you may try this also..

update s
set s.price = 
s.qty * f.pprice
from second s,first f
where s.pid = f.pid

if any mistake..revert me back